# Will an algorithm that constantly changes the order of 10 hash functions be protected from an ASIC?

Tags: hash, brute-force-attack

Let's imagine one hash function that is based on 10 hash functions. For every input, it changes the order of the 10 hash functions. So, for example:

`Hello, World! -> md5 -> sha256 -> sha512 -> sha3_256 ... -> resulted hash -> sha256 (additionally)`

`Hello, World? -> shake_256 -> md5 -> sha256 -> sha3_256 ... -> resulted hash -> sha256 (additionally)`

Will it be impossible to create [an ASIC](https://www.sigenics.com/blog/what-is-an-asic) for such an algorithm? And if yes, what would be effective for brute force?

Comment: What is your actual aim? Why do you want such a randomly ordered hash function? If your actual problem is the passwords, we have already password hashing algorithms like Scrypt and Argon2 that are designed to be a memory-hard that prevents the GPU/FPGA/ASICs. Besides, they have an iteration parameter that linearly affects the cost of brute force. If you are considering [the small input space](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81652/18298) then HMAC is the solution.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for question. In fact, this idea just came to my mind (not sure if I was the first) and it seemed to me that it was protected from ASIC (obviously because I was not in the subject). I implemented it, posted it [on GitHub](https://github.com/NotStatilko/NonHashpass) and hopefully described it as protected from ASIC, but something bothered me, and for good reason :)

Comment: ASIC? do you know [how many transistors the CPU designers use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count)? you play on the beach, they are in the sea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will it be impossible to create ASIC for such algorithm?

No, actually it is quite easy.

The way you'd design a single brute-force core then is that you take a hashing engine for each hash function used, an input generator, a hash validator and a smart interconnect.

Then when you want to brute-force an invocation of ordering 1, the input generator outputs the guess along with routing / ordering information for the interconnect which then sends it to the appropriate engines in the appropriate order. As you are only targeting one ordering at a time, you could possibly even make this a state register of the interconnect. Then, once the first engine has processed the first piece of data, the interconnect receives it back, checks its ordering register and sends it to the next engine, while accepting the next guess for that ordering from the input generator which is promptly sent to the first engine.

> Will it be impossible to create ASIC for such algorithm?

As you have seen exemplified above, there is *no* algorithm which is really hard to brute-force for an ASIC. The best one could hope for is that the *optimal* ASIC configuration would be (close) that of a modern CPU, but even then, chances are that the algorithm will not use specific parts of the CPU, e.g. FP cores, which a dedicated ASIC can drop.

Comment: I would think the best way to make an algorithm hard to brute-force with an ASIC or FPGA would be to make it easy to process with commodity graphics hardware which legitimate users could use.  An FPGA may test more possible keys per joule than a commodity CPU running code for a commodity CPU, but wouldn't be able to process as many keys per joule as a GPU processing an algorithm that was designed to be GPU-friendly.

Comment: @supercat yes, GPUs tend to offer more raw power and make it easier to use large parts of the die. However, password hashing is commonly a server task and so assuming availabiity of a GPU is not something most designers want to make.

Comment: I thought the way to prevent an ASIC board was to construct an algorithm that inherently depends on a couple of GB of RAM.

Comment: @SEJPM: There may be a chicken and egg problem, but if a system has some servers devoted to password hashing, including GPUs in those servers and migrating to password hash algorithms that exploit them could allow servers to offer more bang for the buck.  The migration could be handled by having the database store what hashing scheme is used with each password, and converting passwords to the new format the next time a user logs in.

Comment: @Joshua That can be a very valid strategy to force the ASIC to imitate a CPU as the memory subsystem is a large and highly optimized part of modern CPUs.

Comment: @supercat It very much is a chicken-egg problem. Algorithm designers design for what's available and services design for what they need / what is most profitable. Also while designing to force GPU imitation is probably better than designing for CPU imitation, the extra J/test gains on the ASIC end from the GPU approach _may_ be "too small" to motivate people to buy and run GPUs.

Comment: @SEJPM: GPU designers invest considerable research into maximizing the number of useful operations per joule.  Achieving anything near that level of performance from an ASIC would require a comparable level of research investment.  By contrast, when migrating from a CPU to an ASIC, one can gain improve energy efficiency and reduce research effort merely by omitting things like memory security management which wouldn't be needed for a code-breaking application.